# markdownify post title in jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

It is possible to render Markdown on a post title? For example:

```
---
title: Foo and _other foo_
---
```

I want that output

```
<h1> Foo and <i>other foo</i></h1>
```

Comment: Try`<h1>{{ page.title | markdownify }}</h1>`.

Comment: I'm rendering using `{{ content }}`, but using this don't render the markdown at title... I tried `{{ content | markdownify}}` but nothing... I want to put the title markdownified and the rest of the content normal...

Comment: @HufflepuffBR The `title` and the `content` are two completely different things. The `content` is whatever you have after the second `---` line.

Comment: but in my _layout/default.html it has just `{{ content }}` and renders either title and content

Comment: I expect that your `_layout/default.html` inherits from another template or includes another template and that other template is inserting the page title. You need to modify that other template as per @DavidJacquel's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`markdownify`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) filter to the Liquid tag:

```
{{ page.title | markdownify }}
```

Note that this will wrap the output in paragraph tags (`<p> ... </p>`). If this is not desired (which it probably isn't), you can remove these with Liquid:

```
{{ page.title | markdownify | remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>' }}
```

There [have](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3571) [been](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/5509) [attempts](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/5793) to fix `markdownify` to work with titles so that paragraph tag wrapping doesn't happen, but they haven't materialized and so this clumsy solution is what's available for now. If you'd like to work on it your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `{{ markdownify }}` in `_layout/default.html` worked for me.